# What's the use of callback function in the case given below?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, callback, ecmascript-5

I've written two functions. The first one uses a callback function and the second one doesn't. But both the functions print the same thing. So what's the difference here? Is callback function not needed in this case?

```
//function 1

function printHi(name, callback){
    console.log('Hi '+name);
    callback(name);
}
function printBye(name){
    console.log('Bye '+name)
}

printHi('lavanya',printBye);.

/*************************************************************************/
//function 2

function printHi(name){
    console.log('Hi '+name);
    printBye(name);
}
function printBye(name){
    console.log('Bye '+name)
}

printHi('lavanya');
```

Answer (score 0):

`printHi` in first version is a higher order function while it's not in second.

`printHi` in first version is on it's own when it comes to parameters and it doesn't access global variables but in second version it access a function from global scope `printBye`.

You can read more about higher order functions [here](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/higher-order-functions-composing-software-5365cf2cbe99#:~:text=A%20higher%20order%20function%20is,return%20a%20function%20as%20output.)